# How do you know if an array has consecutive elements that are the same?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting

For example, if I had an array like:

```
arr = ["HI","BYE","BYE","BYE"]
```

Is there a method that would let me know that there are consecutive "BYE"'s in the array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) for that:

```
arr = ["HI", "BYE", "BYE", "BYE"]

arr.each_cons(2).any? { |s,t| s == "BYE" && t == "BYE" }
  #=> true
arr.each_cons(2).any? { |s,t| s == "HI" && t == "HI" }
  #=> false
```

To determine if any consecutive elements are the same:

```
arr.each_cons(2).any? { |s,t| s == t }
  #=> true
```

Note that:

```
enum = arr.each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["HI", "BYE", "BYE", "BYE"]:each_cons(2)>
```

The elements of this enumerator can be obtained by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["HI", "BYE"], ["BYE", "BYE"], ["BYE", "BYE"]]
```

The three elements of `enum` are passed to the block in turn and assigned to the block variables:

```
s, t = enum.next
  #=> ["HI", "BYE"] 
s #=> "HI"
t #=> "BYE"

s, t = enum.next
  #=> ["BYE", "BYE"] 

s, t = enum.next
  #=> ["BYE", "BYE"]
```

Here are a few other ways of doing this:

Use [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) (Ruby v2.2+):

```
arr.slice_when { |a,b| a != b }.any? { |a| a.size > 1 }
  #=> true
```

or [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) (Ruby v1.9.3+) and [Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) (Ruby v.2.2+).

```
arr.chunk(&:itself).any? { |_,a| a.size > 1 }
  #=> true
```

or simply step through the array:

```
arr.any? && (1..arr.size-1).any? { |i| arr[i] == arr[i-1] }
  #=> true
```

`arr.any?` is included in case `arr` is empty.